# ebay sdk - retrieving orders and sync with external DB

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am struggling, literally, trying to figure out how to use th Ebay API in order to retrieve the orders received on a specific merchant account and then store some datas in an external DB.

I have registered to developer.ebay.it, I have built a key pair, both for production and sandbox, then I have tried the api (Browse/getItem)...and then...LOST.

I cannot use the Fullfillment, because I always get a response of Insufficient authorization, even if I create a token, even if I put a real order number... I don't get how to question the API.

Lastly, I am using PHP and I have downloaded the davidtsadler SDK from github. How do I configure an example of getOrder with that SDK? Do you have any link, suggestions, anything?

What I find on internet is not enough clear for my level of knowledge and almost nobody deals with the getOrder call.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ebay API documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/docs#Acc) is fairly clear on how to perform a query:

If you wanted to get a specific Fullfillment policy, then you would need to perform a `GET` request to ebays Fullfillment API using the `/order/{orderId}` path - where `{orderId}` is a real order ID.

In PHP, that *might* go a little something like this:

```
/* Returns a JSON object containing an ebay order */
function getOrder($order_id, $auth_key){
    $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                    'method' => "GET",
                    'header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$auth_key."\r\n" .
                                "Content-Type: application/json"

        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents("https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order/".$order_id, false, $context);
    return json_decode($result);
}
```

Then you could call the method above and retrieve an order using:

```
$order = getOrder("A REAL ORDER ID", "YOUR AUTH KEY");
```

The `$order` variable now holds a JSON object. You can print info from the object using: (This example prints the username associated with the order)

```
echo $order->buyer->username;
```

Finally, please **note** the direct quote from [ebays documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/make-a-call.html):

*"eBay creates and displays an Application token. This token is valid for a limited time span. If you get an invalid token error when you make a call using this token, simply create a new token and use the new token in your call."*

Comment: I definitely LOVE you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)